# react-router Link highlight sibling route active

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a route config similar to this:

```
<Route path="/">
  <Route component={Books} path="books" />
  <Route component={BookDetail} path="books/:bookId" />
</Route>
```

Is it possible to highlight a `Link` active that points to `/books` when `/books/:bookId` is active?

I know this can be achieved with making `/books/:bookId` a child of `/books`, however I'd like to avoid this as `BookDetail` actually replaces `Books` completely in the view.

My current solution is that `BookDetail` is a child of `Books` and `Books` has a condition to render either itself when exactly its route is active or otherwise its children. I'd like to avoid this if possible.

Comment: checkout this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38745288/react-router-link-wildcard-path-matching/38748867?noredirect=1#comment64876946_38748867)

Comment: Interesting approach! Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand it well, but I don't have enough point to post comment. You can pass an extra parameter to

```
<Route path="/">
  <Route component={Books} path="books" />
  <Route component={BookDetail} path="books/:bookId" isDetail={true} />
</Route>
```