# react-router <Link/> Wildcard Path Matching

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In my application, I have a `<NavBar/>` component with a few links which tell the back-end to return a random `location_id` in the specified State. This works well, but because I `browserHistory.replace()` the `random` path with the returned `location_id` path the `<NavLink/>` no longer matches the router path and therefore doesn't remain `active`. Is there a way to make the `<Link/>` component match for every `location_id` including `random`, i.e. a `MA` link would remain active if the url were `/locations/MA/1`, `/locations/MA/random`, or more generally `/locations/MA/*`. but continue to point to `locations/MA/random`?

```
/* ./modules/NavLink.js */
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router'

export default React.createClass({
    render() {
        return <Link {...this.props} activeClassName="active"/>
    }
})

/* Main use of the <NavLink/> */
<NavLink to="/locations/MA/random">Massachusetts</NavLink>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is configure the 'to' attribute of  component to "/locations/MA" so that it remains active for all "/locations/MA/*". But bind it to a 'onClick' function like this

```
    const onLinkClick = (evt) => {
      evt.preventDefault()
      history.push('locations/MA/random')
    }
```

Now although it remains active for all matches, it will only navigate to one URL

Comment: Sometimes an easy solution is just sitting right in front of your face. Was thinking of something way too complicated like I was missing some secret property of `<Link/>`...thanks!